# iOS - SlideMenuControllerSwift and UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, slidingmenu

In my app I'm using UITabBarController and SlideMenuControllerSwift together.

https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

The problem is managing the back button. When I'm in one of the tabs and when I click on some element and go inside to another view the menu button still stays there and is not replaced by the back button.

Are there any sample repositories or other libraries that already do this? This should be a very common use case.

Comment: Try https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController or https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController for tab bar controller.

Comment: You can do that with SlideMenuControllerSwift too. I have used that in my project but with table view.

Comment: It's already done in the slideMenuController library that you are using.

Comment: In SlideMenuControllerSwift back button works if I move to a different view from the slide menu. But back button does not showup when I move to an inner view from within one of the tabs.

Comment: @Prasanth you need setup your project navigation properly, in each Tab put a navigationController and handle the backbutton in your baseViewController, I work this way with this library and works just perfect

Comment: Do you have a sample source that has this working correctly? Or any link to github repos? Any help would be greatly appreciated.